How to manage dependencies for a large mlir project?
Our project is based on several MLIR projects, such as IREE, TT-MLIR, etc., which are based on different versions of LLVM and some other same submodules. It will fail to compile if a small commit is missing before or after the version it is given.
enter image description here
I tried compile separately, but it can be inconvenient for users to compile LLVM for each project separately, as this process is time-consuming.

You need to isolate the third party code from your own builds (compile + linking).
So something along these lines : For each 3rd party package, create a new adapter package which contains your own API (abstract baseclass + factory for example). This package builds the 3rd party code (or uses compiled third party code) into a dll (so you can hide all statically linkable dependencies on "internally" used versions of llvm). From then on your own code will only have to compile against those API's / dlls.

Thanks @PepijnKramer , I find this workload to be quite overwhelming.

How big is the project really? How many people work on it? In the end C++ is just really not that nice when working with multiple components that link with different versions of libraries, you will have to decouple those dependencies somehow. The smallest step is probably to turn your submodules into dll's which allows you to hide the dependencies on the different llvm versions

@PepijnKramer  ,we only have less than 10 people, we tried to base all other projects on the largest project's llvm version, it works

Ok cool. And indeed you can do that if you control all the source code (or at least can build it all).  I think I assumed that some of the libraries where not under your control.
